# Split text File into Access DB using SQL

Tags: sql, vba

All,

This is an example of three lines in my text File  NEW_SCANNING.txt:

```
I;05/29/2013;06:55:37;3124480071200;1;801;1;;1
I;05/29/2013;06:56:05;0049004004827;1;801;1;;1
I;05/29/2013;06:56:09;54491069;1;801;1;;1
```

I want to be able to select what's between the 3rd and 4th " ; ", in this case it would be

```
3124480071200
0049004004827
54491069
```

So what I need the program to do is to search every line that starts with the letter `I` and select what's between the 3rd and 4th `;`.

Then it has to put the first selection in a combobox named SelBarc. If it has done this for the first, it has to move on to the second and so on and so on ...

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Open, read, split to lines then loop;

```
dim lines() as string,i as long
Open "c:\xxx\NEW_SCANNING.txt" for input as #1
    lines = split(Input$(lof(1), #1), vbcrlf)
close #1

For i = 0 to ubound(lines)
    if Left$(lines(i), 1) = "I" then combobox.additem split(lines(i), ";")(3)
Next
```